# Done button does not appear for keyboard type Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD

Tags: iphone, keyboard, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I created a textfield with this properties:

```
keyboardType: Ti.UI.KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD
returnKeyType: Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE
```

I tested this on a iphone device. The decimal pad appears but has no done button.

I also tried with other button types, without success. It seems that it is not possible to set the `returnKeyType` for the `KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD`.

When I change the keyboardtype to `KEYBORD_DEFAULT` or `KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION` it works.

The last option (`KEYBOARD_NUMBERS_PUNCTUATION`) is an alternative that I can use but can someone tell me why it's not working with the `KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

`KEYBOARD_DECIMAL_PAD` doesn't provide a `done` Button. You must add a KeyboardToolbar on your `TextField` to add a Button which close your keyboard, like this :

in your .xml

```
<TextField id="textfield">
    <KeyboardToolbar platform="ios">
      <Toolbar>
          <Items>
              <Button title="Done" onClick="hideKeyboard" />
          </Items>
      </Toolbar>
    </KeyboardToolbar>
</TextField>
```

in your .js

```
function hideKeyboard(e){
  $.textfield.blur()
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Thomas. I will give it a try!

Comment: I tried this approach but I found the animation of the button is out of sync. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41977293/appcelerator-titanium-keyboard-toolbar-out-of-sync-with-keyboard-bug?noredirect=1#comment71132583_41977293

Answer (score 1):

As Provided in archived answers 
there is just a work around for this Issue .
which is to add a Done button to the softkeyboard buttons toolbar
https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/123421/done-button-on-numeric-keypad-can-this-be-done-in-appcelerator

to simplyfy the answer:

```js
var doneButton = Ti.UI.createButton({ systemButton: Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DONE });
$.creditNum_txt.keyboardToolbar = [doneButton];
$.creditNum_txt.addEventListener('focus', function(e) {
    $.creditNum_txt.keyboardToolbar = [doneButton];
    doneButton.activeFld = $.creditNum_txt;
});
doneButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
    e.source.activeFld.blur(); 
});
```

Comment: Works fine. With 5.4.0 Ti.UI.iPhone.SystemButton.DONE is deprecated.
Now: Ti.UI.iOS.SystemButton.DONE should be used instead.